# Nginx $request_uri has duplicated query parameter

Tags: nginx

I found that nginx's $request_uri duplicate the query parameters.

To goal I want to achieve is to redirect any request of naked domain to www domain. Here is a sample configuration.

```
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;    
        location / {
            if ($http_host !~* "^www\.") {
                rewrite (.*) http://www.$http_host$request_uri permanent;
            }
        }
    }
```

The result I got is this:

```
curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8080/pp/\?a\=b

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Thu, 22 Jan 2015 04:07:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.127.0.0.1:8080/pp/?a=b?a=b
```

The query parameter is duplicated in the result; am I missing something here?

Comment: This should be moved to ServerFault. http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 15):

The replication of the query parameters you see is an expected behaviour of Nginx. To change this, you need to add a trailing `?` to the rewrite as in:

```
   server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;    
        location / {
            if ($http_host !~* "^www\.") {
                rewrite (.*) http://www.$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
            }
        }
    }
```

[See Documentation Here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the
>   previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is
>   undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string
>   avoids having them appended, for example:
>
> rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /show?user=$1? last;

However, the configuration given by Aleksey Deryagin is the better and more efficient option for your desired type of redirection because every request will be evaluated by `if` block in your original configuration whether needed or not.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: if you add trailing ``?`` to the rewrite, the whole query string gets stripped, or it does not get duplicated? ie, with the trailing ``?``, would the url become ``http://www.127.0.0.1:8080/pp/?a=b``?

Comment: @dgilperez The URLwould become `http://www.127.0.0.1:8080/pp/?a=b`. Adding a trailing `?` simply stops the query string from being added a second time. As I mentioned in my answer though, using rewrite method in this specific case is not the most efficient way to go about this type of redirection.

Comment: My friend @Dayo: I answer the email you just sent me on my company's contact form, that I reproduce here: *So you initiate a bounty on stackoverflow.com. You get a correct answer but fail to grant the bounty. People like you make people feel reluctant to answer question on SO. Shame on you!*. It's true, I forgot to grant the bounty - you also took 5 days to answer to my clarification requirement. You don't need to worry, the bounty will be auto-awarded in 24h. Though, I must say: there is no need to harass me at my company's website. That is, to say the very least, childish and useless.

Comment: Also: I don't know if the bounty will be auto-awarded to you, which I'd initially expected since your answer is the most accurate. That is still so, even after the above-mentioned attitude.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I am going through a load balancer. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

[if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) (not always, but) so why not try return 301:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  root /var/www;
  location / {
    index index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm it seems to me it has nothing to do with the ``if``, but changing the ``rewrite`` directive for a ``return 301``. In my case I have no ifs, but the rewrite is the same and your option works for me. Any idea why ``return`` works and ``rewrite`` doesn't? How would you write this with a ``rewrite``?

Comment: return 301 is better practice then rewrite, so I use return in my example :)

Comment: I've improved your code to use `$scheme` instead of hardcoding `http://` in the redirect URL, that way the example would work seamlessly both for HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: The official document [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites) says that it's better to use `return` in this case.

Comment: If you want to test the redirect, use 302 instead of 301, so your browser won't cache the redirect.